# Multiple 'start datetime' and 'end datetime'. Generate a new row for each date between start datetime and end datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have a table with numerous columns, among them 'Start datetime' and 'Start datetime'.  Each row therefore has one 'Start datetime' and one 'End datetime'.
I need a new row to be generated for each day between 'Start datetime' and 'End datetime' per row. I will use this table to generate daily volume of ICU beds occupied in a hospital.

Sample data in my table:

```
MRN |'Start datetime' |'End datetime'
----+-----------------+--------------------------------------    
007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016 --will return four rows
008 | 2/1/2015        | 2/3/2015 --will return three rows
```

Desired output:

```
Date       |MRN  |'Start datetime' |'End datetime'
-----------+-----+-----------------+---------------
01/01/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/02/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/03/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/04/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
02/01/2016 | 008 | 2/1/2015        | 2/3/2015
02/02/2016 | 008 | 2/1/2015        | 2/3/2015
02/03/2016 | 008 | 2/1/2015        | 2/3/2015
```

I have tried cursor and some CTE, but I am a novice at SQL and am confused easily. Ideally the solution will allow me to paste my existing query into it's body without modifying my existing query. I'd prefer not to use drop tables because this will eventually be fed into tableau and updated daily.

From my experience table cannot handle drop tables. Thanks for any help.

**Thanks @scsimon  your suggestion helped a ton!  The only problem is that your cte doesn't generate the first row in 'desired output' see below.**

Output using your CTR:

```
Date       |MRN  |'Start datetime' |'End datetime'
-----------+-----+-----------------+---------------
01/02/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/03/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/04/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
```

Desired output:

```
Date       |MRN  |'Start datetime' |'End datetime'
-----------+-----+-----------------+---------------
01/01/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/02/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/03/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
01/04/2016 | 007 | 1/1/2016        | 1/4/2016
```

Hi @scsimon

Below is actual data.  Again thanks for the help. I'm actually on vacation so my internet is spotty so forgive the late reply.  In reviewing the data I realize I neglected to include that it is possible for a patient to be transferred twice on the same date, so that the 'Start datetime' and 'End datetime' are the same date with different times.  I believe this is the cause of my problem.  'Mydate' for all rows where  'Start datetime'and 'End datetime' are the same date equals NULL when it should equal that date.  Forgive my formating, it is taking me so long to format.  Thanks for the help.

My Data:

```
MRN  |'Start datetime'|'End datetime'  
-------+--------------------------------+-----------------------  
0001 |2015-02-27 08:22:12.127 |2015-02-27 10:50:43.243  
0001 |2015-02-27 10:50:43.243 |2015-03-02 08:52:35.000  
0001 |2015-03-02 08:52:35.000 |2015-03-02 12:43:30.790  
0001 |2015-03-02 12:43:30.790 |2015-03-02 17:29:02.147 





My Output:

MyDate|MRN|'Start datetime'|'End datetime'  
-----------------------+---------+------------------+----------------------  
NULL                   |0001|2015-02-27 08:22:12.127|2015-02-27 10:50:43.243  
2015-02-28 00:00:00.000|0001|2015-02-27 10:50:43.243|2015-03-02 08:52:35.000  
2015-03-01 00:00:00.000|0001|2015-02-27 10:50:43.243|2015-03-02 08:52:35.000  
2015-03-02 00:00:00.000|0001|2015-02-27 10:50:43.243|2015-03-02 08:52:35.000  
NULL                   |0001|2015-03-02 08:52:35.000|2015-03-02 12:43:30.790  
NULL                   |0001|2015-03-02 12:43:30.790|2015-03-02 17:29:02.147
```

Comment: Definitely don't use a cursor for this. I gave you a recursive CTE below that will do what you want without creating any new tables in your DB

Comment: If you find yourself doing this a lot you may just want to create a "calendar table" listing out all the dates across some number of years. And if you search by that name you'll find many similar questions and helpful references.

Comment: Updated to handle the datetime problem for you @g.senorsenor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a CTE of dates, then join to your data making 1 row for every date....

```
--the #tempTable is used here for test. Replace #tempTable in your code with your actual table
if object_id('tempdb..#tempTable') is not null drop table #tempTable
create table #tempTable(
    MRN varchar(4),
    [Start datetime] datetime,
    [End datetime] datetime)

insert into #tempTable (MRN, [Start datetime], [End datetime]) VALUES
('0001','2015-02-27 08:22:12.127','2015-02-27 10:50:43.243'),
('0001','2015-02-27 10:50:43.243','2015-03-02 08:52:35.000'),
('0001','2015-03-02 08:52:35.000','2015-03-02 12:43:30.790 '),
('0001','2015-03-02 12:43:30.790','2015-03-02 17:29:02.147'),

('0001','2015-03-03 12:43:30.790','2015-03-06 17:29:02.147'),
('0001','2015-03-15 12:43:30.790','2015-03-16 17:29:02.147'),
('0001','2015-03-16 17:29:02.147','2015-03-17 17:29:02.147')


declare @startDate date, @endDate date
set @startDate = (select min(cast([Start datetime] as date)) from #tempTable)
set @endDate = (select max(cast([End datetime] as date)) from #tempTable)

;with cteDates as(
   select @startDate as myDate
   union all
   select dateadd(day,1,myDate) as myDate
   from cteDates
   where dateadd(day,1,myDate) <= @endDate)

select
    myDate,
    MRN,
    min([Start datetime]) as [Start datetime],
    max([End datetime]) as [End datetime]
from
    cteDates
right join
    #tempTable on myDate >= cast([Start datetime] as date) and myDate <= cast([End datetime] as date)
group by
    myDate, MRN
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**RESULTS**

[image: results]

Comment: @g.senorsenor  Can you tell me what data you tested this with? Also do t forget to up vote helpful answers and accept correct ones

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I listed my question above in the original question! Again many thanks

Comment: @g.senorsenor   Not sure why you got that. Can you check your data? I added some test data here to show you

Comment: @scsimonThanks again for the help.  I updated the question above

Comment: @g.senorsenor updated answer and added in a few more rows of data for testing. that should get you where you need to be... you can edit as you need

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Date table in your database

Just do INNER JOIN to that date table with "ON StartDate >= DateTable.Date and EndDate <= DateTable.Date" condition.

If you don't have that table, it can be easily recreated - physical table, temp table, table variable or table function.

Alternative solution - recursive CTE, but it won't perform better than above solution if you have physical prepopulated date table.